# Can't perform Coverage Tests with Eclemma using JUnit Test on a Wildfly server

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, wildfly, eclemma

I'm trying to run coverage tests for my project, but I'm facing some unexpected troubles. I select my test package, click on "Coverage as -> Run as JUnit Test".
The server is now started (although Wildfly sees it as stopped), but the test is NOT performed, it just stays there waiting. (The tests work if I run them separately without coveraging)

Obviously, if I try to run again the tests again it gives me 0% coverage throwing an exception (server already running). Moreover, I have no way of closing the Wildfly service: I can only restart my computer.

I think this has something to do with a bad configuration of Eclemma, even though my co-worker has identical settings and it works fine to him.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is WildFly supposed to be running for the tests? That seems odd for a unit test.

Comment: You can probably kill the running WildFly instance by using your process explorer to kill Java. The steps vary by operating system.

Comment: Nah, wildfly is just responsable of starting the server and manage properly the connection to a local but external MySQL server. Junit performs tests on the wildfly server which forwards  queries to the MySQL server

Comment: That's what odd, i think the Java VM hides the process to OS because i can't find it in the process explorer